# Why does C print an extra line when reading from a file?

Tags: c, linux, char, fopen

I'm brand new to C and trying to learn how to read a file.  My file is a simple file (just for testing) which contains the following:

```
this file
has been
successfully read
by C!
```

So I read the file using the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

   char str[100];
   FILE *file = fopen("/myFile/path/test.txt", "r");

   if(file == NULL) {
      puts("This file does not exist!");
      return -1;
   }

   while(fgets(str, 100, file) != '\0') {
      puts(str);
   }

   fclose(file);

   return 0;
}
```

This prints my text like this:

```
this file

has been

successfully read

by C!
```

When I compile and run it, I pipe its output to `hexdump -C` and can see an extra `0a` at the end of each line.

Finally, why do I need to declare an array of chars to read from a file?  What if I don't know how much data is on each line?

Comment: This is not the best way to read in a file. You can use `fseek` and `ftell` to find the size of the entire file, then `fread` to read it all in at once to a dynamically sized array.

Comment: To give a useful error message: `file = fopen( path, mode ); if( file == NULL ) { perror( path ); exit( 1 ); }`.  This gives the name of the file and the reason for the failure.  ("this" is not helpful, and assuming the file does not exist in incorrect.)

Comment: @WilliamPursell thank you, I was actually wondering about that and it was going to be the next thing for me to investigate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`fgets()` reads up to the newline and keeps the newline in the string and `puts()` always adds a newline to the string it is given to print. Hence you get double-spaced output when used as in your code.

Use `fputs(str, stdout)` instead of `puts()`; it does not add a newline.

The obsolete function `gets()` — removed from the 2011 version of the C standard — read up to the newline but removed it.  The `gets()` and `puts()` pair worked well together, as do `fgets()` and `fputs()`.  However, you should certainly ***NOT*** use `gets()`; it is a catastrophe waiting to happen.  (The first internet worm in 1988 used `gets()` to migrate — Google search for 'morris internet worm').

---

In comments, [inquisitor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1492471/inquisitor) asked:

> Why does the line need to be read into a char array of a specific size?

Because you need to make sure you don't overrun the space that is available. C does not do automatic allocation of space for strings. That is one of its weaknesses from some viewpoints; it is also a strength, but it routinely confuses newcomers to the language. If you want the input code to allocate enough space for a line, use the POSIX function [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html).

> So is it better to just read and output until I hit a `'\0'` since I won't always know the amount of chars on a given line?

No. In general, you won't hit `'\0'`; most text files do not contain any of those. If you don't want to allocate enough space for a line, then use:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    putchar(c);
```

which reads one character at a time in the user code, but the underlying standard I/O packages buffer the input up so it isn't too costly — it is perfectly feasible to implement a program that way. If you need to work on lines, either allocate enough space for lines (I use `char buffer[4096];` routinely) or use `getline()`.

And [Charlie Burns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1828382/charlie-burns) asked in a comment:

> Why don't we see getline() suggested more often?

I think it is not mentioned all that often because `getline()` is relatively new, and not necessarily available everywhere yet. It was added to POSIX 2008; it is available on Linux and BSD. I'm not sure about the other mainline Unix variants (AIX, HP-UX, Solaris). It isn't hard to write for yourself (I've done it), but it is a nuisance if you need to write portable code (especially if 'portable' includes 'Microsoft'). One of its merits is that it tells you how long the line it read actually was.

#### Example using `getline()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *line = 0;
    size_t length = 0;
    char const name[] = "/myFile/path/test.txt";
    FILE *file = fopen(name, "r");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s\n", argv[0], name);
        return -1;
    }

    while (getline(&line, &length, file) > 0) 
        fputs(str, stdout);

    free(line);
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So is it better to just read and output until I hit a `'\0'` since I won't always know the amount of chars on a given line?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I'm happy to see the getline() reference, why don't we see getline() suggested more often?

Comment: I've removed my three 'comment' answers to the questions posed above; the material from them is now in the main answer.

Answer (score 5):

`fgets` saves the newline character at the end of the line when reading line by line. This allows you to determine wether actually a line was read or just your buffer was too small.

`puts` always adds a newline when printing.

Either trim off the newline from `fgets` or use `printf`

```
printf("%s", str);
```